# session_start in functions.php headers already sent error

Tags: wordpress, header

wordpress site.  at very start of functions.php i have session_start()
but i get an error message saying "headers already sent".  the error_log doesn't give any info about where/what, etc.  is there a way to determine why/where headers are being sent prior to the functions.php being run.

I've tried making sure there's no white space and i've checked header.php, etc.  i've tried using it with the "init" hook and also without it.

Comment: The error message usually also includes “output started at…” and tells you a specific file. You might also want to check if there is a [BOM in any of your files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74154)